# Sampling without replacement from two urns

Tags: probability

Seeking help on the following situation:

1. There are 2 urns, each with balls numbered 1 to $N$.
2. Drawing $N$ balls from urn 1 (without replacement) gives values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$.
3. Drawing $N$ balls from urn 2 (without replacement) gives values $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N$.

What is the probability that $x_i = y_{i+1}$ or $x_i = y_{i-1}$?

I've got a feeling that I'm asking for some form of conditional probability $\text{Pr}(x_i = y_{i+1}\,\text{or}\,x_i = y_{i-1} \vert x_i)$ (not sure if this is correct) but am unsure how to proceed (I'm not a stats expert).

So for example for $N=4$ I might have

- 1, 3, 4, 2 for $x$
- 4, 2, 3, 1 for $y$

In this case, there is one event where $x_2 = y_3 = 3$ (indexing starts from 1). I'd like to know the probability for this to happen for arbitrary $N$.

At first I was thinking that the probability would be simply

$$
p = 2\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2
$$

but this doesn't seem to account for the conditional element in the problem statement.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to list the full set of possibilities for the smallest possible N, and then build up from there.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: what is $i$? Do you mean to include a quantifier, such as "there exists at least one $i$ such that..."?  If so, what would be conditional about this event?

Comment: @whuber I'm looking for the probability that *any* two elements $x_i = y_{i+1}$ or $x_i = y_{i-1}$ for all possible $i = 1\ldots N$. I had thought that my example had made that clear. In that case, there is only one $i = 2$: $x_2 = y_3 = 3$. I am not sure about the conditionality of the event. I'm happy to remove those parts if they confuse. They key question is as stated: "What is the probability that $x_i$=$y_{i+1}$ or $x_i = y_{y - 1}$?"

Comment: A correct statement of the event would be "What is the probability that *there exists* an $i$ such that $x_i=y_{i+1}$ or $x_i=y_{i-1}$?"  Because $y$ is superfluous, the answer will be the same as the chance there exists an $i$ such that $x_i=i-1$ or $x_i=i+1.$ This generalizes the concept of a *derangement.*  But because it does it in a way the permits few simplifications due to permutation invariance, the answer will necessarily be complicated, leading one to consider algorithms to compute it rather than to develop formulas.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the comment. I only understand a fraction of what you said. In case it wasn't obvious: I am not a statistician but merely interested. Are you saying that a closed-form solution does not exist?

Comment: I don't seem to hit the right mark with my questions here on CV. Not really sure what else I can provide here. I thought that the question was fairly clear. I pose a problem statement, and give an example. I also include my thoughts regarding a potential solution. Why can this post not remain open?

Comment: I agree with you: it looks this question was incorrectly closed.